generate dynamic metadata in nextjs and sanity.io
I have used the following approach to generate metadata but its not working. not throwing any error
Its returning the default meta data that i have set in layout.tsx
I am using nextjs and sanity.io
get data function

async function getData(slug: string) {
    const query =
        `*[_type=='post' && slug.current=="${slug}"]{
        title,
        "currentSlug": slug.current,
        shortdescription,
        body,
        author,
        mainImage,
        "categories":categories[]->title,
        "tags":tags[]->title,
        metaTitle,
        metaDescription,
        publishedAt
    }[0]`;
    const result: Post = await client.fetch(query, { revalidate: 60 });
    return result;
}

metadata function
export async function generateMetaData({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }, parent: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {

    const metadata = await getData(params.slug);
    const previousImages = (await parent).openGraph?.images || [];

    console.log(metadata.metaTitle);
    return {
        title: metadata.metaTitle,
        description: metadata.metaDescription,
        openGraph: {
            images: [urlFor(metadata.mainImage).url(), ...previousImages]
        }
    }
}

How can i solve the issue. Thanks
i have tried the below code
export async function generateMetaData({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }, parent: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {

    const metadata = await getData(params.slug);
    const previousImages = (await parent).openGraph?.images || [];

    console.log(metadata.metaTitle);
    return {
        title: metadata.metaTitle,
        description: metadata.metaDescription,
        openGraph: {
            images: [urlFor(metadata.mainImage).url(), ...previousImages]
        }
    }
}

i am expecting the result in browser in form of meta title, description and opengraph image

Solution

i was writing

generateMetaData

instead of

generateMetadata

